# How to identify subscription upgrade or downgrade in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there any way I can identify that the subscription is upgraded/downgraded i.e. plan is changed through some webhook event data.

I'm listening to the `customer.subscription.updated` event but I'm not sure how to identify the plan changes from this event data. Is there any other event which have this information.

Answer (score 0):

`customer.subscription.updated` is the correct event to listen. You can look at its `previous_attributes` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data-previous_attributes) to see the previous plan and find out whether it is upgraded or downgraded.